# Unable to authenticate user from oracle database (python django)

Tags: python, django, oracle

I'm new with python django. I'm trying to create a simple apps that is the user login and connect it to Oracle 11g database. My connection is successful. My problem is when I use the user data (userid and password). It always redirect me on invalid page. It also pointing on the auth lines saying that (Expected :) error.

Here's my code

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from django.contrib import auth
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import OnlineUser

    def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')

def auth_view(request):
    userid = request.POST.get("userid", '')
    userpass = request.POST.get("userpass", '')
    user = auth.authenticate(OnlineUser.USERID=userid, OnlineUser.USERPASS=userpass)
    #user = auth.authenticate(userid=userid, userpass=userpass)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/samplesite/loggedin')
    else: 
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/samplesite/invalid')

def loggedin(request):
    user = get_object_or_404(OnlineUser, pk=id)
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'user': user})


def invalid(request):
    return render(request, 'invalid.html')

def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return render(request, 'logout.html')
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class OnlineUser(models.Model):
    ID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    USERID = models.TextField()
    USERPASS = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table= 'TBL_ONLINE_USER'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ID)
```

templates/login.html

```
<div>
    <form action="/samplesite/auth_view/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type='text' size='25' name="userid" id="userid" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID"/>
        <br/>
        <input type='password' size='25' name="userpass" id="userpass" class="form-control"  placeholder="Password"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="login"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[it should be](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in)

```
userid = request.POST.get("userid", '')
userpass = request.POST.get("userpass", '')
user = authenticate(username=userid, password=userpass)
```

I hope `userid` is user's username